# Moment.js - displaying local 24 hour time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm currently outputting my time as

```
my_time.local().format('LTS')
```

which produces an output like:

```
10:01:52 AM
```

How do I get it to display 24-hour local time, i.e. `10:01:52`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like that:

```
my_time.local().format("HH:mm:ss")
```